# How to arrange Sql rows in a specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have table with up to 50 rows... like given below.

```
ID menu dispOdr ParntID
---------------------  
1   abc  1     0
2   cde  2     0
3   fgh  1     2
4 ghdfdj 2     2
5  tetss 1     1
6 uni    3     0
```

but I want to be sorted

Like

```
ID menu dispOdr ParntID
---------------------  
1   abc  1     0
5  tetss 1     1
2   cde  2     0
3   fgh  1     2
4 ghdfdj 2     2
6 uni    3     0
```

If have any query please let me know.. thanks in advance.

I am using sql server 2014

Comment: What is the logic for the desired order?

Comment: yes order by menu asc.

Comment: In what language does 't' precede 'c'?

Comment: Can you show any queries that you have used so far?

Comment: @gauravbadyal - Care to explain the logic. Keep in mind that all of us are volunteers. No one here is paid for helping you atleast explain the logic for sorting

Comment: I suppose abc starts with space?

Comment: Sorry guys for inconvenience, but I want to sort by their display order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the query below produces the required output:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.menu, t1.dispOdr, t1.ParntID
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.ParntID = t2.ID
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN t1.ParntID = 0 THEN t1.dispOdr
            ELSE t2.dispOdr
         END,
         CASE 
            WHEN t1.ParntID = 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 2
         END,
         t1.dispOdr
```

The first `CASE` expression groups records according to the `dispOdr` of their parent. The second `CASE` places parent on the top of its subgroup. Finally, the last expression used in the `ORDER BY` clause orders all child records within a subgroup.

**Note:** The above query works with one level of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need your current vs. desired output reversed. You say you want the menu column sorted, but it appears that it already is.

So assuming you are actually starting with the second table, you can sort the menu column simply using ORDER BY:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY menu ASC
```